# Calc Percent - Pixels in LESS with Variables

Tags: less

I want to calc the width of my  with Less.

I got two values: The width in % and the space between each  in px.
So I got something like 33% - 40px. These values are Less-Variables.
I want to calc the width using a mixin out of that so I got something like 31.893%.

I tried:

```
width: calc(@widthInPercent - @spaceInPx)
```

but then I got the result -11.37483% which is wrong... This is because LESS did the calculating I think.

Then I wanted to escape it so LESS will not calc it itself:

```
width: calc(~'@widthInPercent - @spaceInPx')
```

But then the variables will not be filled by LESS..

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Escape only subtraction op, e.g.: `calc(@widthInPercent ~'-' @spaceInPx)`.

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple I didn't see it...